# Can I use which command on aliases?

Tags: which

Example:

I have `alias chrome='google-chrome'`. I want `which chrome` to return the same thing `which google-chrome` returns, i.e.:

`/usr/bin/google-chrome`

Is that possible?

Comment: you can use the `-a` switch of which, it will give all possible outcomes, including aliased and the real one.

Comment: @Ketan The -a switch does not work that way.

Comment: `which` is very shell-dependent, so which shell we are talking about?

Comment: Bash, though I am using zsh as well.

Comment: What system are you on? Debian (or derivatives?)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Then your `which` is really this script (when you are using bash): http://sources.debian.net/src/debianutils/4.4/which/ , so in short: then no. You can not get alias from which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you really want `which` to behave this way, you can redefine it as a shell function that way :

```
which() {
  if [ -n "$(type "$1" | grep "is aliased")" ]; then
    command which $(type "$1" | awk '
      {cmd=gensub("[\140\047]", "", "g" , $NF);print cmd}')
  else
    command which "$1"
  fi
}
```

Note that while this should work if your shell is `bash`, the function might need to be slightly modified if you use a different shell.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `which` for this purpose, or better - don't use `which` at all. Use `type <alias_name>` to see alias expansion. Use `type -a <command>` to see all possible categories that a given command can represent - programs from $PATH, shell builtins, functions, aliases. See `type -a echo` for example.

EDIT:

You can also see alias expansion using `alias <ALIAS_NAME>` form, for example:

```
$ alias chrome
alias chrome='google-chrome'
```

To only get a part after `alias <ALIAS_NAME>='` you have parse the output like this:

```
$ alias chrome | sed "s,alias !#:1=',," | sed "s,'$,,"
```

Before doing that in a script make sure than `alias <ALIAS_NAME>` returns zero.

Comment: Well, in my case it prints: `chrome is an alias for google-chrome` which is exactly the point of my question (I want only `google-chrome`).

Comment: @REACHUS do you want `google-chrome` or the full path `/usr/bin/google-chrome` as in the question. This the whole point of the problem.

Comment: @jimmij Preferably just `google-chrome`, but the full path would be OK.

Comment: @REACHUS: see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

in `zsh`, `which` is a `builtin` command that has the same effect of `whence -c`. Which will print out how the each listed command would be interpreted in a `csh`-like format.

In shells that doesn't have `which` as a builtin. `which` is ignorant of alias, builtins, functions and can only search `PATH` for a command with the name.

An example is `which echo`. which may print out `/bin/echo` but echo is(normally) a builtin command also, which would have higher precedence than a binary in `PATH`. Thus the shell would use the builtin and not `/bin/echo`.

Comment: Beware that some systems have a default `which` alias in some shells that call GNU `which` after having fed it the list of known aliases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want which chrome and which google-chrome to return the same response, create an alias for chrome (alias chrome=/usr/bin/google-chrome) and it will.  Aliases are evaluated before commands, so this will change what the command which chrome returns.